# how to get parent category id in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

how to get only parent category ids. not children category ids
i tried this code before which is showing me all ids of categories

```
 <?php  $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();

 foreach($category_ids as $cat_id) {
  $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);
  //echo '<span class="png_bg category_icon"></span>' . $cat_name ;
?>
            <option><?php echo '<span class="png_bg category_icon"></span>' . $cat_name ; ?></option>
   <?php
 }
   ?>          
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be done in a number of ways. One of them is

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach ($categories as $cat)
{
  // if it is a topmost category , it has no parents, ie parent=0
  if($cat->parent < 1)
  {
    echo $cat->category_nicename
    echo $cat->cat_name ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function:

```
<?php get_category_parents($cat); ?>
```

This function accepts several arguments, you can find the full reference on [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents)

Comment: yes i also tried this but i think there was an error in my syntax it show me uncategorized .. can you please post the full code related to this..

Comment: where are you using this? on single or category loop?